# SQL Server 2008 Datetime conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008

Looking to convert **datetime format**

```
20150416 12:29:20:845
```

to

```
20150416 12:29:20:84.
```

I have tried a number of date time conversion but no luck.

Comment: Have you considered removing the last digit/character?

Comment: This seems to have less to do with date/time conversion and more with string manipulation. If you've already got the first item as a string, just replace the last character in it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already converted your date as varchar, you can use this query:

```
DECLARE @V VARCHAR(30) = '20150416 12:29:20:845'
SELECT LEFT(@V,20),STUFF(@V,21,1,'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(22)
SET @Date = CONVERT(Varchar(23), GETDATE(),121) --replace getdate with your value
SELECT @DATE  --2015-04-17 10:56:55.29 format you need
SELECT GETDATE() --2015-04-17 10:56:55.297 actual value 
SELECT CAST(@DATE as datetime)  --2015-04-17 10:56:55.290 if u convert it back
```